# How to work multiple bugs in TFS?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I can't find a good way to work with more than one bug at the same workspace.
This is a very large VS20013 solution (about 4GB) stored in TFS.

Previous experiences with SVN and TFS (smaller solutions):

- Have a copy of the solution/project by each bug I was working on (a
  workspace by bug in TFS). Not acceptable: way too much time and hdd consuming.

I want a way to make changes at any number of files in my solution and be able to create a patch to revert those changes and apply them later. I'll see how to manage the conflicts.

Can any one give me some tips?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shelvesets if you want to switch between working on Bug A and Bug B without creating multiple workspaces.

If your in the middle of working on Bug A and you want to switch to Bug B, create a shelveset then undo your pending changes.  Work on Bug B for a while, when you want to switch shelve your Bug B changes, then unshelve the Bug A shelveset.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was taking a look to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404(v=vs.100).aspx.
 My lack of english didn't ring a bell when I've seen so many times that little button over there.

Comment: If you are running Visual Studio Premium or above, you also get the My Work tab in your Team Explorer to easily suspend what you are working on. This will shelve your code changes and your IDE layout in a way that you can easily start working with it on a later time.

Comment: http://s.ch9.ms/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-How-to-multi-task-with-My-Work <- this is the 'My Work' video. Other than that shelvesets, also remember that your ws doesn't have to have your entire repos in it and you can shadow folders too.